# Conditionally wrapping divs in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically page with divs set up like this. Sometimes each map will have a date and time div following it, but sometimes only some do. I'm trying to use jQuery to wrap each set of map, date, and time in a div with class map-wrap.

```
<div class="withmap">
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="date"></div>
   <div class="time"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="date"></div>
   <div class="time"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="withmap">
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map-wrap">
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="date"></div>
      <div class="time"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map-wrap">
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="date"></div>
      <div class="time"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work correctly. The div inserted before also has a closing tag.

```
jQuery( " .date " ).prev().before(' <div class="map-wrap"> ');
jQuery( " .date " ).next().after(' </div> ');
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nextUntil` and `wrapAll` to solve this:

```js
jQuery(".map").each(function() {
  t = $(this).nextUntil('.map');
  if (t.length) {
    t = t.add(this)
    t.wrapAll('<div class="map-wrap">');
  }
})
```

```css
.map {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.map-wrap {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="withmap">
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="date"></div>
   <div class="time"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="date"></div>
   <div class="time"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
   <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a great solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.map').each(function(index, map){
  //get all the elements after this map, until the next map, and include this map
  var $wrapMe = $(map).nextUntil('.map').add(map);
  
  //only one element(map) ?  ignore
  if ($wrapMe.length > 1) {
    var $wrapper = $('<div class="map-wrap">');
    //put the wrapper before this map
    $wrapper.insertBefore(map);
    //move the elements into the wrapper
    $wrapper.append($wrapMe);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="withmap">
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="time"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="time"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use adjacent sibling selector `+`, `.prevUntil()`, `.addBack()`, `.add()`, `.prev()` to select `.map + .date + .time` groups of elements, then call `.wrapAll()` on collection

```js
$(".map + .date + .time")
.each(function() {
  var prev = $(this).prevUntil(".map").addBack();
  prev.add(prev.prev(".map")).wrapAll("<div class=map-wrap>");
});
```

```css
.map-wrap {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="withmap">
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="time">time</div>
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="time">time</div>
  <div class="map">map</div>
  <div class="map">map</div>
</div>
```